# Vega-Lite, issue with line color specification

Tags: vega-lite

My [example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUADJQBWENgDsQAGhCY6guGhAqQAdxoATetqiLMSGgrgAnXWYUAzGmTSgoDCJjYIAYmxtkTAAVAE8cOAg0TBsGOFUkAA8aKNRQQSQmOEF-BUxtACU2JjZvXQysnPMAZRoALy1UAEYAJlUK7NzMAHU4Fyw0ABZJSXbM7IBhNkEA7UlEsUcANgBmJYAOEABfdvI4BUM3EAhQhBLBAHkcJCg6ULQm1QCaffz0EuwfXUMaGzgodSKbQwZ51cxIQT2aYMBAKVKDLY7ECGJAWCBwTCpUAotEYgD6RjxTTQAG1QMQIXEHm1kajGiAWpIWi1+JImvwmpJgk1BqgRnzpCNJAAtbbKcmUxrM1Q4+mM5mslmc7m8-kjKQjUU7CWCKmoJZLGV07TylmSFYcrk8gUCjUisU6vUrFZGzByplmwaWlU29VCrUAXVdSHRmAJhjxLVJjqlNNlJo9rPZyutasFmodIApusarVd7oVTO9qcktv9mezeoAnIbaW6E4WLSnVaW-RntVnJQ8XXWC57iy2y+3xZ2cw9Hr2G2axAPfen7Vsg3WQ-jCSto6OnT34+hTayvc253atSPK7H81PWTPD2njxWu-razuGYnJEtZ7fyx2z2hnRfd6+ADsH6tvOgZIhkoS2BuOIoGkIAKEgCD0rBobhkSYpqDYSBwo4AQIBuUAQh4GT1ugADkAAS0yhAABJROGGGQfyIYYkTkboIamNsS7IDYADWRyYOE9LCNYuheDYbD8XA3RGCYqA0pJ0n0n8hxIvsZg-Aorjwfc8HONkhzoD+qjCRE2gAI4MDh6gWOopCcckWJqBo9IAJIKLcbF5FEiKqIkQk0MhACqCh0NoUFIIE5gwPGqiGYIxmTmZbnaE5KRHB0OS6hAMDRLE8SuVA-FTAweRoGI-kgGYMx2AZLxJdxqjQBCjTYj4lhKKgJIgNRgh0QxBzMfsSBsVES7YTpjS9WpIABkidmaOliIdrBRyIch2ioauEZRotU0QHhgSEcRDCkfS5EANLhWQWAQLReggrREBIKElAfRxCSpDVPGqHxgnweZolWFoLUxCpcnGPlikaV5bDabpoD6aAiXJaZagiVZNl5HQqI0I5CTOUFmDLegnnea8flIoFQPBXAYURegUUxXkcXGgljXJfFrmk-SGUudlvi5TDMRxKlJVlRVqBVUiykyUcrVk6AU1kDNIBMGOC2c0ZzUgJoasHCTZM6Kta2onBoCbShFtoWumExDhR34adggkcaFEAApSTI-xuoY9GMQA4ixY3sZxP1QH9IAA0JWPoGJYPHBDMlQwpLRw1pVhIyAKMgGj2gY8D2O2XjDlJ0kmV03z2gU0YVPbDTQWheFby53A0UILFPMF+gPNLfzRNV+k4w5Z4ouFRLpVsOVbyy+DUkyQAIiGMMxqShpiNryeL+1xxEcrICq+rc3b73v27IbxmgCcZzTCveWki6W9mwtQA).

My goal is to have the 'handgrenade' line be a solid red which continues as the 'projected handgrenade' dashed line, also red.

I threw the 'knights' in there as a blue line (which apparently works).

Comment: It may be helpful to provide some rationale for the design of your spec. For example, is there a particular reason that you need to include each line as a separate dataset rather than a single dataset with additional attributes? As a single dataset, you could have a field corresponding to the color ("Holy Handgrenades" vs.  "Knights") and a field corresponding to the status (e.g., projected vs. not). The encoding would then be more straightforward. On the other hand, if requiring separate datasets with hard-coding, why not just remove the "color" encoding and hard-code the color like line 45?

Comment: Agree with @sabine. It is also customary to accept and upvote answers you find useful.

Comment: David, sorry if I have missed accepting an answer (there was one about on-hover in legends that I am just now getting back to, but I think I have covered the rest).

Comment: Sabine, We are refactoring our chart code so that we have more generic functions that return the chart layers.  

So in that case it is easier to use separate datasets.  So if at all possible I would prefer that. But if the only way to get to a solution is by combination, I can write some code to do just that.

For your suggestion I did the hard-coding you suggested by adding a `color` field to the encoding with its associated `field` and `scale` fields and removing them from the `stroke` field.

Now my colors are perfect but I lost my legend.

Comment: @GregBartlett, I've included a straightforward answer below. However, an alternative (more in keeping with my suggestion above) would still be to think about how you specify attributes and encodings. For example, you are calculating a new field on your datasets "c", which could instead follow the suggestions above to split it into a "color" and "status" using multiple `"calculate"` transforms, thereby allowing you to have more purposeful and direct encodings for the shared scales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to my comment on the post itself, part of the difficulty here is that the current specification is trying to accomplish the task in a bit of a convoluted way. Essentially what is happening is that each line is created as a separate layer (see the related documentation pages on "Composing Layered and Multi-View plots [here](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/composition.html)), with separate encodings. In order to display them properly, Vega-Lite is trying to merge all these different encodings together to create a single output visualization given all of the information it has. What this means is that it is trying to use a shared scale for the `"stroke"` across all three layers, but it is not entirely sure on how to resolve the conflicts in the changing scale `range`.

The simplest solution (given what you have) is to explicitly tell Vega-Lite that the different `"stroke"` scales should be treated independently of one another, which can be done by appending `"resolve": {"scale": {"stroke": "independent"}}` after the closing square bracket of the `"layer"`. Take a look at the documentation on `"resolve"` [here](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/resolve.html).

However, you may also want to consider refining the specification in some of the ways discussed in my comment above to more directly support the encodings as part fo a single layer in the view.

Comment: Sabine, thank you for the pointer to `resolve`, it fixed so many things :)